# .pro file for Pyside for QT internationalisation

Tags: qt, internationalization, pyside

I am using QT and trying to generate **.ts** translation files using the pylupdate4 command.
I am in the **src** folder of the project and generate my own **.pro** file, which is also in the **src** folder. It looks like this:

```
    SOURCES = rob_gui.py 
    TRANSLATIONS = en.ts \
    germ.ts
```

I have a lot of subfolders in my project **scr** folder and would like to use them all for the translations. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must list all your **.py** files with relative paths in the **.pro** file like this:

```
SOURCES = rob_gui.py \
          dir1\file1.py \
          dir1\file2.py \
          dir2\file3.py \
          ..\dir3\dir4\file4.py
```